# Angular $q library to chain methods after success of an $http request to api?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, asynchronous, angular-promise

I've never written a promise before but I feel like this code communicates my intent.

**Question:** 
How can I asynchronously fire off `matchData()` and `countData()` in the init block, after my http request has been completed, transformed and returned.

```
 function getLangData(langCode) {

    var url = "https://translate.google.com/translate_a/l?cb=JSON_CALLBACK";
      return $q(function(resolve, reject) {    
      $http.jsonp(url, {
        params: {...}
      })
        .success(function (translateAPIData) {
                 return translateAPIData.map(function(){...});
          });
        });

      });
  }

function init() {
  var promise = getLangData(languageCode);
  promise.then(function(mappedData) {
     matchData(mappedData);
  });
  promise.then(function(mappedData) {
     countData(mappedData);
  });  

  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to create you own promise using `$q` as $http method does return a promise by default, you could utilize that by calling `.then` method on it.

```
function getLangData(langCode) {

    var url = "https://translate.google.com/translate_a/l?cb=JSON_CALLBACK";
      //returned promise object from method
      return $http.jsonp(url, {
        params: {...}
      })
      .then(function (response) {
           var translateAPIData = response.data;
           return translateAPIData.map(function(){...});
      });
}
```

**Code**

You could call the promise method just by doing `.then` on that method.

```
function init() {
  var promise = getLangData(languageCode);
  promise.then(function(mappedData) {
     matchData(mappedData);
     countData(mappedData);
  }); 
};
```

Comment: interesting :) let me try it out.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GD6qtc2_AQA Well that was easier than I expected thanks.  marking correct asap.

Comment: Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Comment: Any idea why my mapped data isn't properly being returned in the then blocks of init

Answer (score 1):

Yes $http returns a promise but doesn't necessarily get it back into your init method for your count and match function.  Here is a solution using $q.

```
function getLangData(langCode) {

var url = "https://translate.google.com/translate_a/l?cb=JSON_CALLBACK";
var defer = $q.defer();

$http.jsonp(url, {
    params: {...}
  }).then(function (translateAPIData) {
      defer.resolve(translateAPIData.map(function(){...}));
  });

  return $q.promise;
}

function init() {

 getLangData(languageCode).then(function(mappedData) {
   //Do something with your data here.
   /*
   matchData(mappedData); 
   countData(mappedData);
   */
})
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was just running into this problem.  Because The map promise wasnt returning properly.